# React / Redux array with keys and mapping

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, redux

I have an API which originally returned an array of objects with no key for each object like this:

```
[
{
"id": 4311,
"title": "C43- Miami Bow Cabinet Handles High Quality Stainless Steel (Polished) Handles",
"liked": false
},
{
"id": 2235,
"title": "C43- Miami Bow Cabinet Handles High Quality Stainless Steel (Brushed) Handles",
"liked": false
}
]
```

However it would help my app a lot if I could store this data with the id as the key for each nested object, I have updated my API to return data like this:

```
{
"2235": {
"title": "C43- Miami Bow Cabinet Handles High Quality Stainless Steel (Brushed) Handles",
"liked": false
},
"4311": {
"title": "C43- Miami Bow Cabinet Handles High Quality Stainless Steel (Polished) Handles",
"liked": false
}
}
```

However now I get an error from react - 'props.posts.map is not a function'

I cant understand what has changed to the data, doesnt redux assign a numerical key to each object if one isnt set anyways?

Comment: This is not an array anymore. But you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I think you want to give a look at [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)

Answer (score 1):

`map` is meant to work with arrays only as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

However, you can use `lodash`'s `map` method which also works for normalized objects just like yours.

As an example, you can use:

```
const newArray = _.map(data, (item, key) => {
  // key is the item's id
  return item
})
```

If using a 3rd party module is not an option, you can work with `Object.keys` and get the very same result:

```
const newArray = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

For store this data with the id as the key for each nested object, you can use reduce:

```
arr.reduce(function(map, obj){
  map[obj.id] = {
    title: obj.title,
    liked: obj.liked
}
 return map
}, {})
```